# Why did I get "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected end of handshake data" when I connect to Apollo by erlang's ssl module

Tags: ssl, erlang, apollo

I tried to connect Apollo by ssl module as follow:

```
{State, SslSocket} = ssl:connect(HostName, PortVal, [ {cacertfile, CaFile}, {srp_identity, {"admin", "password"}}], infinity)
```

CaFile is a PEM-encoded ca certificate which was transformed from Apollo's keystore.

but got connect result:

```
TLS connection is closed
```

and exception log in apollo.log

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected end of handshake data
```

My version of erlang is 18.0, Apollo is 1.7.1.

How to solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: It might be worth trying capturing the traffic with Wireshark, and see if anything looks unusual.

Comment: You could try using the openssl tools, you can do `openssl s_client -connect HOST:PORT`, and you can include `-CAfile FILE` to set your CA cert(s). If there's any problems `openssl` can give you PLENTY of diagnostics :)

Comment: Not saying `{State, SslSocket}` is necessarily wrong... but... normally `{ok, SslSocket}` would be what one might expect.

Comment: @Michael I got 'Verify return code: 0 (ok)' from openssl.......